# Node.js Crypto work only for string with length less than 15

Tags: node.js, encryption

I have two function to encrypt and decrypt strings in node.js and both work fine, til input string have length less than 15 characters and above this they will not work. Below are both function i used in nodejs with crypto module.

```
encrypt: function (input, password) {
    try{
        input = input.toString();
        var m = crypto.createHash('md5');
        m.update(password);
        var key = m.digest('hex');

        m = crypto.createHash('md5');
        m.update(password + key);
        var iv = m.digest('hex');

        var data = new Buffer(input, 'utf8').toString('binary');

        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv.slice(0,16));
        var encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
        var encoded = new Buffer(encrypted, 'binary').toString('base64');

        return encoded;
    }catch (ex) {
        return input;
    }
 },


 decrypt: function (input, password) {
     try{
        // Convert urlsafe base64 to normal base64
        var input = input.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        // Convert from base64 to binary string
        var edata = new Buffer(input, 'base64').toString('binary');

        // Create key from password
        var m = crypto.createHash('md5');
        m.update(password);
        var key = m.digest('hex');

        // Create iv from password and key
        m = crypto.createHash('md5');
        m.update(password + key);
        var iv = m.digest('hex');

        // Decipher encrypted data
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv.slice(0,16));
        var decrypted = decipher.update(edata, 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');  
        var plaintext = new Buffer(decrypted, 'binary').toString('utf8');
        return plaintext;
     }catch (ex) {
         return input;
     }
  }
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What does *"they will not work"* mean? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error? If not, how does the data that you get out of it differ from the data you expect?

Comment: Not working means when i am trying to encrypt a string whose length is greater than 15 characters like 'This is a string which have more than 15 characters in it. '  it gives an base64 string and when i am trying to decrypt it  can't get original text. While if same thing i will try with string less than 15 characters it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the documentation:

[`cipher.update(data[, input_encoding][, output_encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_input_encoding_output_encoding)
[`cipher.final([output_encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_final_output_encoding)

And you're doing

```
var encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
```

which means that the `update()` call returns a Buffer, because you didn't specify an output encoding and `final()` outputs a binary string.

When the Buffer is coerced into a string through concatenation, the two parts have different encodings and because you're reading it as a single piece with `new Buffer(encrypted, 'binary')`, it will throw an error during decryption:

> [Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length]

It's always a good idea to look what exceptions are thrown. Currently, you're simply ignoring the exception `ex` if any is raised.

#### Solution

Provide an output encoding during encryption:

```
var encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'binary', 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
```

and decryption:

```
var decrypted = decipher.update(edata, 'binary', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');
```

---

#### Other considerations:

Key and IV should be comprised of bytes. Currently, you're using MD5 to produce a hex-encoded key of 256 bit. Instead you should use PBKDF2 (thousands or millions of iterations and a random salt) with a binary output size of 384 bit. You can use the first 256 bit for the key and the rest for the IV. Then you would send the salt along with the ciphertext.

Answer (score -4):

You have a small IV which limits it to 15 characters. The IV should be equal in length to the plain text. You can repeat your key multiple times to generate a large IV.

Comment: No, the Initialization Vector must be 16 bytes or 128 bit for AES in CBC mode.